# Execution failed for task ':expo-updates:compileReleaseKotlin'

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm using expo sdk 45 platform: Android. Once I built the app this error prompt, I've tried upgrading and downgrading 'expo-updates' since the error is occuring at 'Android -> node-modules' but nothing came of it. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this problem im my project:

- removing "expo-updates" from my package.json,
- deleting node_modules folder,
- running npm install and rebuild.

now is solved

Answer (score 1):

Try building the app with `./gradlew app:assembleRelease` instead of `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: Thanx unfortunatly that didn't work for me, but I found a fix.

Comment: @RelieEssom can you provide your "fix" so that others can try..

Comment: What is the fix?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I accidentally did `yarn add expo-updates`, instead of `expo install expo-updates`, resulting in the wrong version being locked.

Doing `expo install expo-updates` installed and locked the correct version. Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to `expo-updates@~0.14.4`, not sure if will work for anyone else though. Heads up expo doctor will downgrade this to `expo-updates@~0.13.4` on sdk ^45.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because all the templates reference the React Native dependency by range, like `implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'.` Usually this dependency gets resolved from the local Maven repo in ./node_modules/react-native/android but since it has been published to Maven Central it's now grabbing the very latest RC.

You can resolve this problem by forcing the React Native dependency to the version you expect with something like this `implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.68.2!!'` in `/android/app/build.gradle`. The `!!` is shorthand for restricting Gradle from upgrading if your project or its transitive dependencies depend on a newer version.

Thanks to [jaredh](https://github.com/jaredh) from GitHub.
issue: [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35204)